# How do I convert UUID in string (char array) to static uint8_t adv_data[31]

Tags: c++, c, arrays, arduino, uuid

I have an iBeacon UUID like this `"3bdb098f-b8b0-4d1b-baa2-0d93eb7169c4"` and I need it to look pretty much like that:

```
static uint8_t adv_data[31] = { 0x02,0x01,0x06, 0x1A,0xFF,0x4C,0x00,0x02,0x15,0x71,0x3d,0x00,0x00,0x50,0x3e,0x4c,0x75,0xba,0x94,0x31,0x48,0xf1,0x8d,0x94,0x1e,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xC5 };
```

I need either a method to convert that in code but a one off method of converting this "by hand" would be cool too (plus the arduino code wouldn't have to deal with the conversion everytime)

Comment: That uuid has 16 bytes of data. Where should they go in your 31-byte array?

Comment: The values given in the binary array don't match the hex values in the string.

Comment: I know they don't match, that's why I said "pretty much like this" ... it's only an example of what I needed

Answer (score 3):

Red two characters at a time, convert them to a number corresponding to the hexadecimal value. Do in a loop. Skip the `'-'` character when you encounter it. Set the "current" element in the array to the value. Set "current" to the next element in the array.

Something like this *pseudo* code

```
while (not at end of string)
{
    char1 = get next character from string;
    char2 = get next character from string;
    value = make int from hex characters(char1, char2);
    array[current++] = value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for your problem

```
char *uuid = "3bdb098f-b8b0-4d1b-baa2-0d93eb7169c4";
static uint8_t adv_data[32];  //your uuid has 32 byte of data

// This algo will work for any size of uuid regardless where the hypen is placed
// However, you have to make sure that the destination have enough space.

int strCounter=0;      // need two counters: one for uuid string (size=38) and
int hexCounter=0;      // another one for destination adv_data (size=32)
while (i<strlen(uuid))
{
     if (uuid[strCounter] == '-') 
     {
         strCounter++;     //go to the next element
         continue;
     }

     // convert the character to string
     char str[2] = "\0";
     str[0] = uuid[strCounter];

     // convert string to int base 16
     adv_data[hexCounter]= (uint8_t)atoi(str,16);

     strCounter++;
     hexCounter++;
}
```

Comment: What happens if the number of hex-digit chars in `uuid` exceeds `32`. Can't you protect against it? Why use `atoi` for conversion when you can simply subtract `'0'` for `0-9` and `'a' - 10` for `a-f`?

Comment: As i have said in the comments, "you have to make sure that the destination have  enough space" which means i leave that to the OP to protect against it add code to check bounds. Why not simply subtract '0' for 0-9 and  'a'-10 for a-f? You have to understand that '0' is not the digit 0 and 'a' is not the hex A. These character have equivalent ASCII codes 'a' = 97 and '0' = 48. When you subtract 'a' -10, that gives you a result 87 which is the character 'W'. atoi function make sure you convert the number in the string to its integer counter part exactly as it appears.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using a library function to convert to numeric form, you can simply subtract `'0'` for characters `0 - 9` and `'a' - 10` (or simply `'W'`) for characters `a - f` to preform the conversion. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define MAXC 32

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char *uuid = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "3bdb098f-b8b0-4d1b-baa2-0d93eb7169c4";
    uint8_t data[MAXC] = {0};

    size_t i, ui = 0, di = 0, ulen = strlen (uuid);

    for (;di < MAXC && ui < ulen; ui++, di++) {
        if (uuid[ui] == '-') ui++;    /* advance past any '-'  */
                                      /* convert to lower-case */
        if ('A' <= uuid[ui] && uuid[ui] <= 'Z') uuid[ui] |= (1 << 5);
        data[di] = ('0' <= uuid[ui] && uuid[ui] <= '9') ? uuid[ui] - '0' :
                    uuid[ui] - 'W';   /* convert to uint8_t */
    }

    if (di == MAXC && ui != ulen) {  /* validate all chars fit in data */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: uuid string exceeds storage.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("\n original: %s\n unsigned: ", uuid);
    for (i = 0; i < di; i++)
        putchar (data[i] + (data[i] < 10 ? '0' : 'W'));
    putchar ('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Output**

```
$ ./bin/uuid_to_uint8_t

 original: 3bdb098f-b8b0-4d1b-baa2-0d93eb7169c4
 unsigned: 3bdb098fb8b04d1bbaa20d93eb7169c4
```

(**note:** you can add a further check that `uuid[ui]` is a valid *hexadecimal* character or `'-'` before attempting the conversion for additional validation).